# Rust: rotate vector, more complex solution takes less time

Tags: rust

I have doing some Rust leetcode's and was wondering why in this problem, where you have to rotate an array, but takes much more time to execute than others.

My solution (300ms):

```
impl Solution {
    pub fn rotate(nums: &mut Vec<i32>, k: i32) {
        let i = nums.len() - 1;
        let mut x = 0;
        while x < k as usize {
            let e = nums[i];
            nums.remove(i);
            nums.insert(0, e);
            x = x+1;
        }
    }
}
```

Faster solution, with 3 loops and more memory use (10 ms):

```
impl Solution {
    pub fn rotate(nums: &mut Vec<i32>, k: i32) {
        let k: usize = k as usize;
        let length = nums.len();
        let mut n: usize = 1;
        while (((n * length - k) as i32) < 0) {
            n += 1;
        }
        let mut padding: usize = n * length - k;
        let mut res = Vec::with_capacity(length);
        for i in 0..length {
            res.push(nums[(i + padding) % length]);
        }
        for i in 0..length {
            nums[i] = res[i];
        }
    }
}
```

I would have expected the simple solution with a single loop and less memory usage to take less time.

Comment: Are you aware of slice's [`rotate_left()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.rotate_left) and [`rotate_right()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.rotate_right) methods?

Comment: Yeah, I came across them after I sent my solution.

Comment: Hint: think about what happens when you do `nums.insert(0, e)`. If you were to implement this method, what would you need to do?

Comment: Benched with criterion both of your solutions and std's `rotate_right()`, results: `rotate additional vec   time:   [1.1873 µs 1.1919 µs 1.1966 µs]`, `rotate remove-insert    time:   [13.525 µs 13.568 µs 13.625 µs]`, `rotate std              time:   [31.487 ns 31.561 ns 31.664 ns]`, so clearly (and unsurprisingly) std is orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: Your first solution also has three loops, with two of them inside `remove` and `insert`. In that case the loops are nested which makes things a lot slower.

Comment: Also, a better solution which is almost at the same speed as std: `*nums = [&nums[k..], &nums[..k]].concat()`.

Comment: It makes sense that std performs better. I don't find it so intuitive that `rotate additional vec` performs ten times better than `rotate remove-insert`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first `rotate()` has time complexity O(N^2) while the second is O(N).

That's because `insert(0)` needs to shift all elements one place next, which means `memmove()` which touches all elements, so time proportional to the amount of elements.